# NSPredicate filtering an array based on a localised string entry

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate, nslocalizedstring

We have a main plist file, which includes our data source.
[image]

The above shows an example of one sub dictionary from the root array.

I would like to create an NSPredicate to search/filter the Category Name. But not the value in the plist as this is a localized string key. For instance when this is used we use:

```
cell.categoryNameLabel.text = NSLocalizedString([cellData objectForKey:@"CategoryName"], nil);
```

I have an NSPredicate that works on the Search Terms, but would also like that updated to look at localized string values instead as well is that is possible.

I have tried to convert it to an nslocalizedstring approach but it does not seem to work:

```
NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K.%@ LIKE[cd] %@)",@"CategoryName",NSLocalizedString(@"YELP_CAT_NAME_AIRPORTS", nil), searchText];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in the %K.%@, if you look at the final predicate I believe that it will put quotes around the %@, which is not what you want (guessing by the dot notation).

**EDIT:**

You could also use a predicate block:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [NSLocalizedString(evaluatedObject[@"CategoryName"],nil) isEqualToString:@"searchString"];
}];
```

**EDIT 2:**

The above predicate works by returning any row that matches the above criteria. To perform a more complicated search, just increase the number of requirements to return true. For example if you want to see if the localized string inside of the 'CategoryName' either contains a string or equals a string you could do something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSString *localizedText = NSLocalizedString(evaluatedObject[@"CategoryName"],nil);
    BOOL perfectMatch = [localizedText isEqualToString:@"searchString"];
    BOOL containsString = [localizedText rangeOfString:@"searchString"].location !=NSNotFound;
    return (perfectMatch || containsString);
}];
```

Comment: Right I don't think I want that. But it leads to the question what should it be :)

Comment: I think you can just do "%K.CategoryName LIKE[cd] %@)"

Comment: But that would output CategoryName.CategoryName? The key is CategoryName == %K

Comment: Right! I didn't know about the %K! Could you search on the localized string key?  In this case the YELP_CAT_NAME_AIRPORTS?   If not you could also use blocks.  See my edit.

Comment: I'm looking to search for the localised string not the key. So let's say the localised string is 'airports' I want to compare that text to a searchText string. That's what I am not sure how to do... Does the block approach suggest that, not at my machine at moment. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it takes the value in the CategoryName key, localizes it and then compares the localized string to the search term.

Comment: This does not quite work... I can get it to return a result, but it doesn't matter what is typed. For example if I type the second category name from the localized strings, the first category is the only one that returns. Secondly I need to do a LIKE[cd] or CONTAINS[cd] comparison to get this to work. The other option is that I just Localize the plist file and do it that way.

Comment: Correction: This works fine. But how do I change this to be like the original attempt with CONTAINS[cd] or LIKE[cd]. Thanks